# How to edit Wordpress dns-prefetch

Tags: wordpress

How I can try to edit my wordpress dns-prefetch

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s0.wp.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//secure.gravatar.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
```

I need to edit all of those to include https, so my site not error

Comment: Those links are protocol relative.  If your site is using https already, they should be fetching resources with https as well as long as it's available.  If you're not already using SSL encryption on your own site, why do you care if the other links are delivered via https?  Read more: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below to completely remove dns-prefetch:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_resource_hints', 2 );
```

add that code in your functions.php file or you can go [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/06/resource-hints-in-4-6/) to learn more about wordpress resource hints.

Comment: OP did not ask how to completely remove pre-fetch.  Further, those links are protocol relative, so they can already be delivered using https without removing them.

Comment: Yeah its protocol relative but I think the OP wants to change some value there which I provided a link with a very detailed instruction on how to do so.